# Why do these two seemingly identical Cypher queries differ so greatly in speed?

Tags: performance, neo4j, cypher

I have a query like this as a key component of my application:

```
MATCH (group:GroupType)
WHERE group.Name = "String"
MATCH (node:NodeType)
WHERE (node)-[:MEMBER_OF]->(group)
RETURN node
```

There is an index on `:GroupType(Name)`

In a database of roughly 10,000 elements this query uses nearly 1 million database hits. Here is the `PROFILE` of the query:

[image: Slow Query Profile]

However, this slight variation of the query which performs an identical search is MUCH faster:

```
MATCH (group:GroupType)
WHERE group.Name = "String"
MATCH (node:NodeType)-[:MEMBER_OF]->(group)
RETURN node
```

The only difference is the `node:NodeType` match and the relationship match are merged into a single `MATCH` instead of a `MATCH ... WHERE`. This query uses 1/70th of the database hits of the previous query and is more than 10 times faster, despite performing an identical search:

[image: Good Query Profile]

I thought Cypher treated `MATCH ... WHERE` statements as single search expressions, so the two queries should compile to identical operations, but these two queries seem to be performing vastly different operations. Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to start by saying that this is not actually a Cypher problem. Cypher describes what you want, not how to get it, so the performance of this query will very vastly between say, Neo4J 3.1.1 and Neo4J 3.2.3.

As the one executing the Cypher is the one that decides how to do this, the real question is "Why doesn't the Neo4J  Cypher planner not treat these the same?"

Ideally, both of these Cyphers should be equivalent to

```
MATCH (node:NodeType)-[:MEMBER_OF]->(group:GroupType{name:"String"})
RETURN node
```

because they should all produce the same results.

In reality, there are a lot of subtle nuances with dynamically parsing a query that has very many 'equivalent' expressions. But a subtle shift in context can change that equivalence, say if you did this adjustment

```
MATCH (group:GroupType)
WHERE group.Name = "String"
MATCH (node:NodeType)
WHERE (node)-[:MEMBER_OF]->(group) OR SIZE(group.members) = 1
RETURN node
```

Now the two queries are almost nothing alike in their results. In order to scale, the query planner must make decision shortcuts to come up with an efficient plan as quickly as possible.

In sort, the performance depends on what the server you are throwing it at is running because coming up with an actionable lookup strategy for a language that lets you ask for ANYTHING/EVERYTHING is hard!

RELATED READING

- [Optimizing performance](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/performance/)
- [What is Cypher?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cypher_Query_Language)

Comment: So if a query is executing slower than it should, we should just try variations through trial and error until we arrive a query that is sufficiently efficient on our version of Neo4j?

Comment: @slbelden Yes. I would also recommend adding `CYPHER <version>` to your queries to make sure that the Neo4j receiving it is compatible with the syntax's you are using. (safety thing) Use Profile heavily to analyze queries you need to run often.

Comment: As a side note, I'd like to add that I improved some of my Cyphers by an order of magnitude simply by upgrading the Neo4J version I was using. (no cypher change at all ... I use `(a)-[*..10]->(b)` way to often for tracing things)

Comment: @slbelden Another way you can prove this isn't a Cypher problem is by running the profile again after removing the index on group. Your Cypher never said to use an index (or knew) but Neo4j changed the plan to use the available index. You changed the performance without changing the Cypher. This is why you should also think about your db schema when designing your Cyphers.

Answer (score 0):

`MATCH ... WHERE <pattern>` isn't the same as `MATCH <pattern>`.

The first query performs the match, then uses the pattern as a filter to perform for all built up rows.

You can see in the query plan that what's happening is a cartesian product between your first match results and all :NodeType nodes. Then for each row of the cartesian product, the WHERE checks to see if the the :GroupType node on that row has is connected to the :NodeType node on that row by the given pattern (this is the Expand(Into) operation).

The second query, by contrast, expands the pattern from the previously matched `group` nodes, so the nodes considered from the expansion are far less in number and almost immediately relevant, only requiring a final filter to ensure that those nodes are :NodeType nodes.

EDIT

As Tezra points out, Cypher operates by having you define what you want, not how to get it, as the "how" is the planner's job. In the current versions of Neo4j (3.2.3), my explanation stands, in that the planner interprets each of the queries differently and generates different plans for each, but that may be subject to change as Cypher evolves and the planner improves.

In these cases, you should be running PROFILEs on your queries and tuning accordingly.

Comment: So [this statement in the official Neo4j documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/where/#where-introduction) is incorrect? "For MATCH and OPTIONAL MATCH on the other hand, WHERE adds constraints to the patterns described. It should not be seen as a filter after the matching is finished."

Comment: This is a kinda dangerous explanation. While the syntax's technically mean different things, Cypher describes what you end up with, not how to get it. Both Cyphers can get away with using the same plan because they both retrieve the same kinda of data.

Comment: @Tezra Fair enough, I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @slbelden Checking on that one. My take on it is it's misleading to take a firm stand either way on whether it's incorporated into the match or filters after, it will depend upon the query and the planner.